# How do you create and add a .apnx file to a Kindle book to display real page numbers?

Tags: kindle, epub, mobi, kdp, kindlegen

I have a decent amount of experience creating epub files and converting them to .mobi using Kindlegen or Amazon Kindle Previewer 3 for self publishing on KDP. I'm looking to add the "real page numbers" feature to a book (this is useful in textbooks because people still tend to like to reference page numbers when citing). Amazon rolled out this feature in 2011, but I can find no current or relevant information for how to do this, other than general guidance that Kindle references an embedded ".apnx" file to identify the page numbers. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KindleGen supports both [NCX pagelists](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/NCX#PageList) and [ADE page-maps](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Adobe_Digital_Editions#Page-map). I.e., you'll have to add a pagelist/page-map and you'll also have to add page target markers in the (X)HTML files.

Note that the official Amazon tools won't generate APNX files. However, [KindleUnpack](https://github.com/kevinhendricks/KindleUnpack) can generate them from a mobi file generated by KindleGen.

You could also generate KFX files with the unofficial [KFX plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=272407). When transferred to an eInk device, the firmware will automatically generate the APNX files.

Comment: Thanks so much, this does help. A point of clarification, is there any purpose to using Kindleunpack or creating a KFX file other than personal use/testing the book? As I understand it from reading these forums, Amazon will deliver a KFX file when the book is purchased and downloaded by a reader... Or did I misinterpret?

Comment: You don't need to use the unofficial tools. However, since the official Amazon tools don't generate APNX files for testing, it's the only way to preview embedded page numbers, unless you generate an epub3 book and preview it with iBooks.